# < and > characters in wordpress shortcode content

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a Wordpress blog on coding. I created a shortcode to display the code in a certain format.

The problem is when I use the character `<` (as in ‘less than’) inside the shortcode content, it seems to be interpret it as html tag `<` and totally messes up my shortcode.

I read online that this was introduced in WordPress with `do_shortcodes_in_html_tags` which parses the content for HTML tags.

Is there a way to avoid this feature and display the `<` character as is in the shortcode content?

Comment: Does `&lt;` not work?

Comment: thanks Niet, that works.